# Get subsequent batch of users (UsersApi)

Tags: docusignapi

Currently using UsersApi to get the list of all users on a DocuSign account. The API has a default count limit of 50 and a max of 100.

One of our accounts has more than 100 users, which means I get a nexturi that I could use to fetch the next batch, but I don't see how I can use it with the available functions in the SDK.

Has anyone used the SDK to fetch the next batch of users (or other elements)?
Is that doable, or should I code the fetching of next batches manually (with my own classes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# SDK for example:

After the initial call, you have the `NextUri` parameter, right? value like "/users?start_position=50&count=50", right?
Then when you make another call you need to use the ListOptions like this:

```
var res = usersApi.List(accountId, new UsersApi.ListOptions { startPosition = "100" });
```

Comment: Yes! That's a good idea. I'll try it but I don't see why it shouldn't work. Thanks!